# Active Directory search using DN (distinguished name)

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, distinguishedname

I am working on a PHP function to get the manager of an active directory user(using the users email address).
After getting the manager, I want to get the managers e-mail address.

I use this code to get the manager:

```
    //Search using a filter.
    $result = ldap_search($connect,$ldaptree, "(mail=useremail@domain.de)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($connect));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);


    // iterate over array and print data for each entry
    echo '<h1>Show me the users</h1>';
    for ($i=0; $i<$data["count"]; $i++) {

        echo "Manager: " . print_r($data[$i]["manager"]) . "<br />";
```

The code is working and I am getting correct values when searching for users email or other attributes.
But when I am searching for the manager `echo "Manager: " . print_r($data[$i]["manager"]) . "<br />";`
then I get the DN (distinguished name) of the manager.
For example: "Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => CN=LASTNAME\, FIRSTNAME,OU=01_User,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=de ) Manager: 1"

Now the problem is, when I try to search for the managers email address, using the DN as filter

```
$result = ldap_search($connect,$ldaptree, "(DN=".$data[$i]["manager"]."") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($connect));
```

Then I get an "Array to string convertion error".
If I use print_r($data[$i]) to convert to string, then I get "Error in search query: Bad search filter".

So my question is, how can I use the DN to get the attributes of the user behind the DN?
Is it possible to filter for a DN?
Do I have to process the DN string?

Hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the Manager by calling `ldap_search` directly with the DN of the manager as BaseDN and a filter of `(objectclass=*)`

```
$result = ldap_search($connect, $data[$i]['manager'][0], '(objectclass=*)');
```

I updated the answer with the feedback from the OP.

Comment: Thankyou very much! Now I understand.
But now I get "ldap_search(): Search: Invalid DN syntax" Error.
Same if I use "print_r($data[$i]['manager'])".

Comment: How can that be? Because I am using the DN I got from the manager attribute of a User.

Comment: OK, your code is the correct way to search for a DN.
My problem is, that when I get that DN array value of a Users Manager and convert it to a string, then there is always the ArrayID set as first character in the string. I solved the problem by removing the first char of the string. But how can this happen? Or what am I do wrong?!
"$managerDN = substr($managerDN, 1);"

Comment: Thats what I get: "1CN=LASTNAME\, FIRSTNAME,OU=01_User,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=de".
As you can see, there is "1" set as the first char. But why?

Comment: So its working when I use "substr($managerDN, 1);" to remove the first char. But this is only a workarround. Not a elegant way to solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few issues:

1. The error message is correct. You are giving it an array, not a string. I think you mean to use the `manager` attribute there (`$data[$i]["manager"][0]`, not `$data[$i]`). In the search results, attributes are all presented as arrays, even if they are single-valued attributes (like `manager`).
2. You are missing the closing parenthesis in the LDAP query. It should look like this:
3. If you are indeed using Active Directory, the attribute is called `distinguishedName`, not `DN` (I believe some OpenLDAP implementations use `DN`, which is why that shows up in documentation).

So your code should look like this:

```php
$result = ldap_search($connect,$ldaptree, "(distinguishedName=" . $data[$i]["manager"][0] . ")") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($connect));
```

Comment: Yes thats right. It has to be '$data[$i]["manager"]'.
But I still get the same Error. If I use "$data[$i]["manager"]" then I get "Array to string conversion" Error. If I use "print_r($data[$i]["manager"])" then I get "Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => CN=LASTNAME\, FIRSTNAME,OU=01_User,DC=int,DC=domain,DC=de ) Manager: 1"

Comment: Right. The attributes are often returned as arrays themselves, even if they are single-valued. So use `$data[$i]["manager"][0]`.

Comment: Thankyou! This solved the array to string conversion problem!